# Jquery tooltip customization isnot working, how to handle it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

i  am trying to customize my tooltip with jquery. The positionning and add some effect and also customize a bit the design. Tooltip is correctly displayed but when i try to add some effects or positionning, nothing happen.

I try this :

```
$(".tip").tooltip(
{
    show: { delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' },
    hide: { delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' }
});
```

or this :

```
$(".tip").tooltip({
        position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" }
    });
```

Here is code i actually get

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-SortTable.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".tip").tooltip({
            show: { delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' },
            hide: { delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' }
        });
   });
</script>
```

I would like at least css and effect work but nothing happen sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



  $( ".selector" ).tooltip({  
    hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 }
    });
```

Comment: I try this but unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: `$(function() {
            $('.tip').tooltip({  
               items: 'a.tip',  
               content: 'Test content…',  
               show: "slideDown",   
               close: function(event, ui) {
                  ui.tooltip.hover(function() {
                     $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(500, 1); 
                  },
                  function() {
                     $(this).fadeOut('500', function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                     });
                  });
               }
            });
         });`

Comment: Try above code to see any effects please add the jquery links which you can see in my answer